# Calculate the sum of a particular table cell's value created by s:iterator tag in JSP from Action class of Struts2?

Tags: struts2

I want to calculate the sum of the particular property from action class which is displaying in JSP as HTML Table using `<s:iterator>` tag.

**JSP code is:**

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Buyer</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <s:set var="sumTotal" value="%{0}" />
    <s:iterator value="eal" status="entries">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="date"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="materialName"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="quantity"/><s:property value="unitName"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="buyer"/></td>
        <td>&#8377;<s:property value="total"/></td>
        <s:set var="sumTotal" value="%{+#attr.total}" />
        <td><s:property value="remarks"/></td>
        <td>
            <a href="/HomeMaker/showUpdateEntryForm?entry.idEntry=<s:property value="idEntry"/>">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/HomeMaker/deleteEntry?entry.idEntry=<s:property value="idEntry"/>">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Sum Total</th>
        <td colspan="4"><s:property value="#sumTotal"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to calculate the sum of table heading "Total" and display that below in last row with the heading "Sum Total".
Please help me..

Comment: What type is your `total` property?

Comment: Isn't your JSP already doing that?

Comment: Pay attention, you was not closing correctly the `</td>` containing your Delete `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<s:set var="sumTotal" value="%{+#attr.total}" />
```

to

```
<s:set var="sumTotal" value="#sumTotal + total" />
```

And you do not need to use `%{0}` inside first `<s:set>` tag, simple 0 will work.

```
<s:set var="sumTotal" value="0" />
```